# Step functions in the proof of Lusin's theorem by Stein and Shakarchi

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

All measurable sets and functions in this article refer to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Let me introduce some technical terms and theorems first. By a **characteristic function** $\chi_E$ of $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$, we mean a function defined by
$$\chi_E(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&,x\in E\\
0&,x\notin E.
\end{cases}
$$
Further, we define a **step function** to be a finite sum
$$f=\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k\chi_{R_k},$$
where $R_k$'s are rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $a_k$'s are constants. Then we have the following theorem.

> **Theorem 4.3** *Suppose $f$ is a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then there exists a sequence of step functions $\{\psi_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ that converges to $f(x)$ for almost every $x$.*

Now we can dig into the proof of Lusin's theorem.

> **Theorem 4.5 (Lusin)** *Suppose $f$ is measurable and finite-valued on $E$ with $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ of finite measure $m(E)$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a closed set $F_\epsilon\subseteq E$ such that $m(E\setminus F_\epsilon)\leq\epsilon$ and $f|_{F_\epsilon}$ is continuous.*
>
> *Proof.* Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of step functions such that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere. Then we may find sets $E_n$ so that $m(E_n)<\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $f_n$ is continuous outside $E_n$. By Egorov's theorem, we may find a set $A_\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ on which $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $m(E\setminus A_\frac{\epsilon}{3})\leq\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Then we consider
> $$F'=A_\frac{\epsilon}{3}\setminus\bigcup_{n\geq N}E_n$$
> for $N$ so large that $\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Now, for every $n\geq N$, $f_n$ is continuous on $F'$; thus, $f$ (being the uniform limit of $\{f_n\}$) is also continuous on $F'$. To finish the proof, we merely need to approximate the set $F'$ by a closed set $F_\epsilon\subseteq F'$ such that $m(F'\setminus F_\epsilon)<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

As noted above, we can approximate a measurable function defined on **all** of $\mathbb{R}^d$ by step functions, but in the statement of Lusin's theorem, we only have a measurable function defined **locally** on $\mathbb{R}^d$. How do we bring in $\{f_n\}$? How do we find those $E_n$'s?
Finally, is each $E_n$ contained in $E$?

Thank you for your patience. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I should quit fixating on those step functions, and it could be possible to generalize Theorem 4.3 to a local version. What really confuses me now is how to find $E_n$ with small measure. All I know is that because each $f_n$ is constant on some subsets of $E$, it is continuous on each of these subsets (with possibly distinct values).

Comment: Extend $f$ by zero to all of $\mathbb{R}^d$. The extension is measurable. The $E_n$ exist because step functions are continuous almost everywhere. I think the $E_n$ need not be contained in $E$.

Comment: @Mason It seems right, and if we let $D_n$ be the set of points where $f_n$ is discontinuous, then by choosing an open set $E_n\supseteq D_n$ with $m(E_n\setminus D_n)<\frac{1}{2^n}$, it is totally possible to find $E_n$ with designated measure!!! Thank you. If you write an answer, I would vote for you.